# Looping UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm creating button and I want to loop 14 times, 2 rows and each row having 7 buttons and between each button a little space, how can I do this?

This my code:

```
var tileButton = UIButton()
func createButton() {

            for i in 0...13 {

                tileButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 530, width: 50, height: 50)
                tileButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
                tileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
                tileButton.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "cell"), for: .normal)
                tileButton.addTarget(self, action: "tileButton", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                tileButton.setTitle("\(String(i))", for: .normal)
                view.addSubview(tileButton)

            }
    }
```

When I run this code is displayed just 1 button!

Comment: What is the current behavior? You should probably include that information.

Comment: var tileButton = UIButton() should be come under the for loop because no new instance is made if it is outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
let BUTTON_PADDING: CGFloat = 10
func createButton() {

        for i in 0...13 {
            let y: CGFloat = i < 7 ? 530 : 600

            let tileButton = UIButton(frame: .zero)

            tileButton.frame = CGRect(x: (50*i) + BUTTON_PADDING, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)
            tileButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
            tileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            tileButton.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "cell"), for: .normal)
            tileButton.addTarget(self, action: "tileButton", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            tileButton.setTitle("\(String(i))", for: .normal)
            view.addSubview(tileButton)

        }
}
```

Comment: The project is run but when I click a button  there was crash !! and no spaces between each buttons !
@MichałKwiecień

Comment: I've edited answer - now the position should be correct. The crash after click is because of wrong using .addTarget. Read about selectors

Comment: Thanks, but the position of the rows are not equal ! why ?! @Michał Kwiecień

Answer (score 0):

This is the most accurate solution :

```
let buttonWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 7
var xAxis : CGFloat = 10

        for i in 0...6 {

            let letterButton = UIButton()

            letterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xAxis , y: self.view.frame.size.height - (buttonWidth * 2) - 20, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)

            letterButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
            letterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            letterButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "cell"), for: .normal)

            let letterButton2 = UIButton()

            letterButton2.frame = CGRect(x: xAxis, y: self.view.frame.size.height - buttonWidth - 20, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)

            letterButton2.layer.masksToBounds = true
            letterButton2.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            letterButton2.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "cell"), for: .normal)

            xAxis = xAxis + buttonWidth

            view.addSubview(letterButton)
            view.addSubview(letterButton2)

        }
```